# How can I use Javascript to use one input field of a form to show the rest?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form with more than one input field - the first is always shown, and if it gains focus, that should show the rest; then, if *all* of the input fields lose focus, the form should go back to showing the first input field only (which was what shown to begin with.) I've wrestled with the various focus/blur events in JS, and can't figure out how to make this work.

```
<form class='myform'>
  <input id='a' placeholder="This is always visible"></input>
  <input id='b' placeholder="Not shown till #a is selected"></input>
</form>
<div class='outside'>
  Let's say, when you click here, or use tab keypresses to leave the above input fields, after you were in either input field, the form should then only shown input#a.
</div>
```

I understand how to make the fields show, when the first one gains focus. But when focus leaves the form entirely, I can't figure out exactly where to bind the `blur()` event, so that I know I've lost focus from all the input fields.

My attempt so far: I bind focus to ".myform input" and blur to ".myform", try to move my cursor from #a to #b, the blur triggers on #a, bubbles up to the handler on .myform, immediately hides #b, and now I can't check if #b gained focus or whether the entire form lost it.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Tried to clarify that the accepted solution should also work when using the keybd to navigate, instead of only for mouse clicks... thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer to support keyboard tab events.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I don't think it works... I tried your fiddle demo and it doesn't seem to do the trick. Am I missing something? Tabbing out of #b or shift-tabbing from #a leaves #b visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jU5Q9/4/)

```
 $("#b").hide();
$(document).ready((function(){
  $( document ).on( "click  keydown", function() {
      if($("#a").is(":focus")){
          $("#b").show();
      }
      else if($("input").is(":focus")){
           //there is some input with focus.. if you want to manage this situation code goes here
      }
      else{
          $("#b").hide();
      }      
  });
}));
```

Comment: Almost there ... but it doesn't work if I keyboard-tab out of the input fields, because it relies on mouse events. Is there a better way than trying to capture keypress events?

Comment: @sameers do you want #b hidden if you press tab after #a is focused?

Comment: If I press _shift_ tab, yes... because tab from #a goes to #b, at which point it shd remain visible. I tried to clarify in my OP.